# Clarification of the notion "faithful" of representations of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: notation, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\pi:A\to B(H)$ a $*$-representation for $A$ ($H$ is a Hilbert space).
From lecture I learned that we call "$\pi$ is faithful" if $\pi$ is injective.
But why is it not allowed to say that $\rho:A\to \mathbb{C}$ is faithful, if $\rho$ is an injective state of $A$? I guess that it's also forbidden to say "faithful" for injective $*$-homomorphisms $f:A\to B$ on $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$.

My question is therefore: What does "faithful" really mean? Where does the notion "faithful" come from?

Comment: $*$-representations are the analogues of groups actions, and faithful actions are precisely the injective ones, so there's a motivation for the nomenclature. Note, however, that there are no injective states on $A$ (excluding the trivial cases $A=0,\mathbb{C}$). A state $\rho$ is faithful if and only if the associated (GNS) representation $A\to B(A_{\rho})$ is faithful. In the case of a $*$-morphism $f:A\to B$ between C*-algebras, we don't really see $A$ "acting" anywhere, so we lose the idea of an action and the nomenclature is simply not used.

Answer (score 1):

For a $*$-homomorphism, *faithful* is the same as *one-to-one* (I usually avoid *injective* because it has another meaning in the theory).

It is precisely for states where the difference is significant. A functional can only be one-to-one if its domain is one-dimensional. That is, unless $A=\mathbb C$, any state on any C$^*$-algebra is not one-to-one. On the other hand, many states are faithful and these are particularly important states (among other things, because their corresponding GNS representations are faithful).

As for the origin of the name, as Luiz mentioned, it probably has to do with the fact that a faithful representation gives you an embedding.

Comment: why any state on any $C^*$ algebra is not one to one?

Comment: Because the only way a linear functional can be one-to-one is if the domain is one-dimensional.

Comment: I see.I misunderstood:"$\tau(a^*a)=0$ implies  $a=0$ "is equivalent to "$\tau(a)=0$ implies $a=0$".

Comment: Only when $\tau$ is multiplicative. That's what this question and answer are about.

Answer (score 0):

> According to *[this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-Star-AlgebraRepresentation.html)* Wolfram page *faithfulness* is a property of the pair $(H,\phi)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $\phi:A\rightarrow B(H)$ is an *injective* $*$-homomorphism.

I think the following example there is helpful.